# How can 'nt!ObFastDereferenceObject's cmpxchg fail?

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, windows-kernel

I am currently working through 'Practical Reverse Engineering', with one of the tasks asking me to decompile the "ObFastDereferenceObject" kernel routine. Most of the assembly is fairly easy to understand, but i cannot wrap my head around the use of this 'cmpxchg' instruction.

I do understand the cmpxchg instruction overall (cmp dest, rax; if equal mov dest, source; else mov rax, dest), but in this function I cannot see how cmpxchg could fail.

```
nt!ObFastDereferenceObject:
 sub     rsp, 28h
 mov     r9, rdx
 prefetchw [rcx]
 mov     rax, qword ptr [rcx]
 mov     r8, rax
 xor     r8, rdx
 cmp     r8, 0Fh
 jae     nt!ObFastDereferenceObject+0x29

nt!ObFastDereferenceObject+0x19:
 lea     r8, [rax+1]
 lock cmpxchg qword ptr [rcx], r8
 jne     nt!ObFastDereferenceObject+0x33

nt!ObFastDereferenceObject+0x24:
 add     rsp, 28h
 ret

nt!ObFastDereferenceObject+0x29:
 mov     rcx, r9
 call    nt!ObfDereferenceObject
 jmp     nt!ObFastDereferenceObject+0x24

nt!ObFastDereferenceObject+0x33:
 mov     rdx, rax
 xor     rdx, r9
 cmp     rdx, 0Fh
 jb      nt!ObFastDereferenceObject+0x19

nt!ObFastDereferenceObject+0x3f:
 jmp     nt!ObFastDereferenceObject+0x29
```

Because (in line 4) rax gets a copy of the _EX_FAST_REF struct, pointed to by rcx,
and because neither rax nor rcx nor the object pointed to by rcx change,
the cmpxchg, comparing rax and [rcx], should always evaluate to equal as far as I understand it.
(Which is highly unlikely considering, that the function has a section only being executed if this cmpxchg evaluates to 'not equal')

Comment: It is multithreaded code. The value in memory may be changed by another thread.

Comment: It is practically self-documenting, the unnecessary `prefetchw` yells loudly "the value may be stale because it was read early".